# Is there any way to route to error page whenever error occurs in http api in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 50+ http api's in my application. I want to route to a page when error message or error occurs in an api i don't want to go to all service and add routing there i want to do it dynamically and simple? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Http Interceptor](https://medium.com/javarevisited/what-are-http-interceptors-and-how-to-use-them-in-angular-59fcb4efc235) to implement that.

**Http Interceptor** is standing between the client-side and the server-side and it catches every request and every response between.

So, you can catch the HTTP Response errors and navigate the user, something like:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any> | any> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(event => {
        // catch the success response
      }, err => {
           // navigate in case of errors
           this.router.navigate(['/error-page'])
      })
    );
  }

}
```